# Pass Input value to parent component function

Tags: react-native, input, ref

I'm trying to develop a react-native APP.
I'm very experienced with Java & PHP, but something is puzzling me with react-native.
Basically, I'm trying to obtain a working Login PAGE (just for practical exercise) but I'm struggling when I try to pass value from child component value (for example, the Password Input) to parent component function (the LoginForm).

Here's a specific code: [PasswordInput]

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { HelperText, TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';

class PasswordInput extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            password:''
        };
    }
    getPassword() {
        return this.state.password;
    }

    login(){
        alert(this.state.password)
    }

    OnChangesValue(e){
        console.log(e.nativeEvent.text);
        this.setState({
            userName :e.nativeEvent.text,
        })
    }

    changePassword(e){
        console.log(e.nativeEvent.text);
        this.setState({
            password :e.nativeEvent.text,
        })
    }

    hasErrors(text){
        let result=true;
        if(text.length>10 || text.length==0){
            result=false;
        }
        return result;
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <TextInput
                    ref="pass"
                    name="password"
                    onChange={this.changePassword.bind(this)}
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                    label="Password"
                    left={<TextInput.Icon name="lock" onPress={() => {
                    }}/>}
                />
                <HelperText type="error" visible={this.hasErrors(this.state.password)}>
                    Password too short!
                </HelperText>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default PasswordInput;
```

and here the LoginForm component:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Component, createRef } from "react";
import {View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {Button, Card, Title} from 'react-native-paper';
import EmailInput from './login_components/email_input';
import PasswordInput from './login_components/password_input';
import {useRef} from 'react/cjs/react.production.min';

class LoginForm extends React.Component {

    passwordInput = createRef();

    submitForm(){
        alert(this.passwordInput['password'].value);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Card style={styles.detailRowContainer}>
                <Card.Title
                    title="Signup!"
                    subtitle="Inserisci i tuoi dati per eseguire il login"
                />
                <EmailInput/>
                <PasswordInput ref={this.passwordInput}/>
                <Card.Actions>
                    <Button mode="contained" type="submit" style={styles.loginButtonSection} onPress={() => this.submitForm()}>
                        LOGIN
                    </Button>
                </Card.Actions>
            </Card>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    loginButtonSection: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '30%',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    detailRowContainer: {
        flex:1,
        flexDirection:'row',
        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent:'center'
    },
});
export default LoginForm;
```

My goal (for now) is to understand how to receive the PasswordInput value in my LoginForm component in order to print the password in the alert (submitForm() function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps easier would be to go about it in the opposite direction and have a reusable component which is given props to alter its appearance and functionality.

Landing page:

```js
// importing Input.tsx from folder: components
import Input from '../components/Input';

export default function LandingScreen() {
  // Hooks for email and password
  const [email, set_email] = useState<string>('');
  const [password, set_password] = useState<string>('');

return(
       <View>
            <Input
              placeholder="Email"
              onChangeText={(text) => set_email(text)}
              keyboardType="email-address"
            />
            <Input
              placeholder="Password"
              onChangeText={(text) => set_password(text)}
              secureTextEntry={true}
              keyboardType="default"
            />
       </View>
)
```

Here is an example of an Input component:
(so instead of passing information from an child to parent we now have a reusable component which accepts a few props defined in its interface).

imported Input.tsx found in folder: components

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

interface Props {
  placeholder: string;
  onChangeText: (text: string) => void;
  secureTextEntry?: boolean;
  keyboardType: any;
}

const Input: FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const { width } = useWindowDimensions();
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        style={[styles.input, { width: width * 0.8 }]}
        autoCapitalize={'none'}
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
        secureTextEntry={props.secureTextEntry}
        onChangeText={props.onChangeText}
        keyboardType={props.keyboardType}
        placeholderTextColor={'black'}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Input;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#e3e3e3',
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
  input: {
    padding: 15,
  },
});
```

A great way to get started with a sign-in screen is with "formik" and "yup" which enables quick creation of input fields and client-side validation with hooks.